# C# Linq - Return different Objects depending on Queryresult (if/else)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which I query for some data under certain conditions it returns OKObject and under other conditions NotSoGoodObject.
I would like to know how it´s possible to do this with Linq.

Basically:

```
var myList = context.Orders......ToList();
object obj=null;

if(myList.All(x=>x.myenum==1)){
  obj=OKObject {....};
 }
else if(myList.Any(x=>x.myenum==-1)){
 obj=NotSoGoodObject{....} ;
  }
}else{
 //No idea yet
}
```

I would have to do this for ~10 more enums.

Is there an way to do the above with one single Linq Query?

Comment: `GroupBy(x => x.MyEnum)`?

Comment: `myenum` doesn't seem to be an `enum`, but rather an integer. You seem to be testing for `All` and `Any`, what else might you test with? And what happens if more than one test is true?

Comment: Yes, it´s an enum :X. All=true means that everything is okay, Any=true that you have to look at it again and it is not possible that both return true.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of:

```
public List<object> GetDataObject(int enumInt) {
    var myList = context.Orders......ToList();
    return myList.Where(x => x.myenum == enumInt).ToList();
}
```

Although, I don't recommend using object.

EDIT:

Given your comments, you could try:

```
var myList = context.Orders......ToList();

var notSoGoodObjects = myList.Where(x => x.myenum == -1 || x.myenum == anotherBadEnum || ...).ToList();

var okObjects = myList.Where(x => x.myenum == 1 || x.myenum == anotherGoodEnum || ...).ToList();

//If you have other objects you can use LINQ's `.Where()` method to only filter those results.
```

Comment: I have to use different Variables of the instances, so a single Method is not possible... maybe with Reflection, though.

Comment: Can you update the OP with what the OKObject and NotSoGoodObject look like? Are they complete different looking objects???

Answer (score 0):

The only way that seems possible, is if you had a Class, for example `NumbersGoodEnough`, and one of it's properties was set with a linq query

But that only makes your code **look** cleaner here

Or simply try using a method to put all of the code in, that would be my first choice

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to try it without two dozen if/else and thought that it might be possible with Linq.